# Christmas Lights on Vinyl fences

Tags: fence, vinyl

My question is... How do I install Christmas lights (C7 or C9) in a nice uniform row atop all of my vinyl fence ? I don't want to glue, screw or tape 
them on.

Comment: have you tried searching google for 'christmas light fence clips'?  In the image results, found 2 good candidates in the top 25.

Answer (score 5):

Zipties (aka cable ties). Be sure to use ones that are UV-resistant.

[image: Ziptie]

Cost pennies each, strong enough for the application you're talking about, non-damaging and non-permanent, and easy to remove when done.

Comment: And the zip ties are available in a range of colors so they can be matched to the vinyl fence so as to be less noticeable. A natural color nylon zip tie would work out with a white vinyl fence.